# How to stop web.py server which run as windows service

Tags: python, windows, windows-services, web.py, httpserver

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import thread
import json
import sys
import web
import os
import logging
from ReleaseDistribution.server_actions import Actions
from ReleaseDistribution import logging_setup
import time
from win32api import SetConsoleCtrlHandler
import traceback

class TestHttpService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
_svc_name_ = "GlobalDeploymentReleaseService"
_svc_display_name_ = "Global Deployment Release Service"

def __init__(self, args):
    win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(lambda x: True, True)
    self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)

def SvcStop(self):
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
    self.run_service=False

def SvcDoRun(self):

    try:
        app = web.application(urls, globals())
        http_server = web.httpserver.runsimple(app.wsgifunc(), ('0.0.0.0', 8088))
        http_server.run()
    # raise any exceptions, we can't usually recover well
    except Exception as error:
        logger.error('exception...{0}'.format(traceback.format_exc()))
        sys.exit(-1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(TestHttpService)
```

I am new to Python and window service api. I need to convert a python script into a windows service. I managed to do the first step but I couldn't find a way to stop it. I got "[SC] ControlService FAILED 1061: The service cannot accept control messages at this time." when

I I don't have infinite loop to check self.run_service flag and call sys.exit() to terminate the service. Can you guys help me with it?

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I am using web.py for http server, win32service to convert it to a windows service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def SvcStop(self):
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
    web.httpserver.server.interrupt = KeyboardInterrupt()
```

source code of [wsgiserver.**init**.py](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/web/wsgiserver/__init__.py): start() method poll interrupt to determine whether stop the server.

```
     while self.ready:
        self.tick()
        if self.interrupt:
            while self.interrupt is True:
                # Wait for self.stop() to complete. See _set_interrupt.
                time.sleep(0.1)
            if self.interrupt:
                raise self.interrupt
```